# How to perform python rsplit() in spark sql or split on last occurrence of delimiter in spark sql?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My input is

```
'Apple-Pie-1024'
```

Desired output is

```
'Apple-Pie'
```

I can do this using python `rsplit()` method as

```
s.rsplit('-',1)[0].strip()
```

which will give me the desired output

how can i get similar output with spark sql?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using an UDF , the python code snippet that you created

## UDF

```
split_udf = F.udf(lambda x : x.rsplit('-',1)[0].strip(), StringType())

input_list = [
  (1,"Apple-Pie-1024")
]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,['num','col1'])

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('r_split',split_udf(F.col('col1')))

sparkDF.show()

+---+--------------+---------+
|num|          col1|  r_split|
+---+--------------+---------+
|  1|Apple-Pie-1024|Apple-Pie|
+---+--------------+---------+
```

## Built in Spark SQL -

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('r_split'
                                 ,F.concat(F.split(F.col('col1'),'-').getItem(0)
                                           ,F.lit('-')
                                           ,F.split(F.col('col1'),'-').getItem(1)
                                )
                            )

sparkDF.show()

+---+--------------+---------+
|num|          col1|  r_split|
+---+--------------+---------+
|  1|Apple-Pie-1024|Apple-Pie|
+---+--------------+---------+
```

Built-in [SQL functions](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/732/ggbaker/content/spark-sql.html#udf) are preferred (also [here](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/732/ggbaker/content/spark-sql.html#python-jvm)) because your data does not get passed back and forth between the JVM process and the Python process, which is what happens when you use a UDF.

## Quick Fix For Desired output

This solution is intended to provide you a way to tackle data inconsistency and the way to approach it within the Spark Env.

You can update the `split_udf` to tackle edge cases as below -

```
#### REGEX to extract only characters from the string
split_udf = F.udf(lambda x : "-".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", x)), StringType())

input_list = [
  (1,"Apple-Pie-1024")
 ,(2,"ApplePie-12345")
]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,['num','col1'])

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('r_split',split_udf(F.col('col1')))

sparkDF.show()

+---+--------------+---------+
|num|          col1|  r_split|
+---+--------------+---------+
|  1|Apple-Pie-1024|Apple-Pie|
|  2|ApplePie-12345| ApplePie|
+---+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: second solution works only when the string has two occurrences of delimiter, I also have values in column with one occurance of it ex. ApplePie-12345  for which i need ApplePie as output. need a solution which can handle both :)

Comment: Well you wont be able to get a one off solution for this , as the logic is based on a delimiter , its the preprocessing step of data where this shd be taken-care of. I have updated the answer with a quick fix for this.Kindly upvote and accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using Spark SQL functions (requires v2.4.0 or later). I use this for getting the parent directory for filesystem paths (or parent paths in URLs), so it's a little more general purpose than OP's needs. OTOH, it isn't a general purpose `rsplit`.

```py
from re import escape

def parent_path(col, sep='/'):
    arr = F.split(col, escape(sep))
    sliced = F.slice(arr, 1, F.size(arr) - 1)
    return F.concat_ws(sep, sliced)

input_list = [
  (1, "Apple-Pie-1024")
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(input_list, ['num', 'col1'])
df = df.withColumn('parent', parent_path('col1', sep='-'))
df.show()

+---+--------------+---------+
|num|          col1|   parent|
+---+--------------+---------+
|  1|Apple-Pie-1024|Apple-Pie|
+---+--------------+---------+
```

Note that Spark SQL's `split` function takes a regex for the pattern, so it needs to be escaped here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using `regexp_extract`:

```py
input_list = [
  (1, "Apple-Pie-1024")
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(input_list, ['num', 'col1'])
df = df.withColumn('parent', f.regexp_extract('col1', r'(.*)-', 1))
df.show()

+---+--------------+---------+
|num|          col1|   parent|
+---+--------------+---------+
|  1|Apple-Pie-1024|Apple-Pie|
+---+--------------+---------+
```